# Kendo UI Multiple Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, gridview, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to create a grid where it gets two entries to bind from  two tables in the database, and save the result in another result table.
To explain more I have attached a picture of the needed grid,

[image]

So as you guys see in the picture,  : 1) I want the servers list to be bound in the horizontal header (from servers table),2) and I want to bind the application list in the vertical row. That way I check inside the grid when an application is deployed on a server.

My question is how to achieve this? is there a kendo component or any other component that will help me doing this job?

Answer (score 0):

A lot can depend on the data model.

The KendoUI PivotGrid https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pivotgrid/index might be what you need and works cleanly with categorical form data.

If you prepare your own pivoted data, as the results of a SQL Server pivot query, a normal KendoUI Grid may suffice.

If you prepare you own data, as the result of a dynamic pivot query, the columns could be different each time.  You will need to learn about htmlhelper Grid, such as discussed in https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/how-to/Binding/grid-bind-to-datatable.

A dynamic data source can also be handled in just jQuery (with no htmlhelpers), such as discussed in https://www.telerik.com/blogs/dynamic-data-in-the-kendo-ui-grid

Comment: Thanks for your comment Richard, I'll try them out